# Overriding chain operations ? Greedy

Tags: python, overriding, operation

Is there a way to override/implement a chain operation.
What I mean ? lets take multiplication it handles a * b
In my case I use `__mul__` to binary-OR the two operands and then apply destructive operation, which means that the result is different for 3 operands.

Here is pseudo code

```
class MyClass:

def fun(self, lst):
   for i in lst : x |= i
   ... destructive ops ...
   return x

def __mul__(self, rhs): return self.fun([self,rhs])
```

Now those two are equivalent :

```
 a * b   <==>  fun([a,b])
```

but those are not :

```
 a * b * c   <=/=>  fun([a,b,c])
```

because the multiplication is done in two steps and the function call in one.

Is there a way to make multiplication greedy, so that it can collect same operation if repeated ? The same goes for "+" ?

Comment: If you want your examples to be clearer, use actual Python code, not pseudo code. `__mul__` is a method on classes.

Comment: i put self kw ...

Comment: Why do you have to perform the destructive step as part of your multiply operator?

Comment: that is the logic of the operation..i'm using mult as a way to do it like expressions.. which easier on the eyes and can be combined with +,/, |, & ... which is the goal

Comment: You are going to have a hard time going down that road. You are better off building a syntax tree using the operators, and then applying your operations using some compiler function.

Answer (score 0):

Destructive operations can make code very hard to reason about. Try to work out a pure, functional solution instead of hacking around operator precedence.

Comment: python only allows per OP override, not per EXPR ;(

Comment: Does not matter. Wrap the results in "UnaryExpression" or "BinaryExpression" types. You will have a "compile" function to reduce it to an actual value.

Comment: So short of rewriting the Python interpreter (to override syntax semantics) you just need to embed your language at level inside Python.

Comment: Take a look at how SQLAlchemy does it. It allows you to build table expressions using objects representing columns and regular Python operators. The results of such expressions are not directly usable (they represent a syntax tree) but they are passed on to other functions that know how to interpret them.

Comment: Building a compiler is a very common programming exercise, it is much easier than you might think. Some languages lend themselves very well to such tasks (Scheme, Lisp and Haskell are some examples) while others like Python have some friction.

Comment: Binary operators in Python, as they are interpreted, cannot distinguish from the inside if an expression is enclosed or not. That is, in the expression (a * b * c), the *ab* particle does not know that there is a *c* attached to it. Instead, if you define your `__mul__` operator to wrap the operands in a placeholder syntax tree object, then you can easily see chains of operations when you pass that object to a final processing function.